# IE: Child element loses animation when parent is temporary hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer

After hide and show of the parent element, the child element no longer rotates(loses it css3 animation).

Removing parent element animation and doing hide/show won't cause the same issue(The issue only occurs when the parent element also have an animation)

I was testing in IE 11.
Is this a known issue?

Here is the snippet in codepen(copied below) http://codepen.io/agirma/pen/byIEd

```
/*-------- CSS start ---------*/
@-webkit-keyframes show_content {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes show_content {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate_content {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate_content {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#parent {
    display:block;
    background:gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: show_content 4s;
    -ms-animation: show_content 4s;
    amimation: show_content 4s;
}
#child {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: rotate_content 1s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: rotate_content 1s linear infinite;
    amimation: rotate_content 1s linear infinite;
}

/*------------CSS end----------*/

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleVisibility()">toggle display</button>
<script>
    function toggleVisibility() {
        var div = document.getElementById('parent');
        div.style.display = div.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this issue is "known". I found it myself a couple of weeks ago when IE-testing a webapp I'm building. I finally got around to looking at it today, and upon noticing the same conditions for occurrence that you've listed, I decided to submit a bug report for IE. I was just about to do that when I found this question.

**My bug report:** 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/941104/ie-11-bug-with-nested-css-animations-upon-display-of-previously-hidden-parent

**Update:**
The bug was successfully reproduced by Microsoft engineers and will be investigated.